# Can I disable VA2065 - Server-level firewall rules should be tracked and maintained at a strict minimum?

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, azure-sql-database

We have an automated workflow which allows database admins to create a firewall rule for their own IP address when they need to access the database via SSMS. At 11:00pm every evening we have an automated runbook which clears all these rules out.

The problem is, there is no way for me to create a defined baseline since the number (and names) of these rules is always changing dynamically. So it's become a bit of cat-and-mouse. Azure keeps flagging the baseline mismatch and I just go ahead and define the new baseline to match. This is very cumbersome and the resource drain is not sustainable. Is there any way I can preserve Advanced Data Security for my database server but exclude this particular check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to use **Disable Rule** (see screen-shot). This does not disable the entire category **Check for Vulnerability assessment findings on your SQL databases should be remediated**, rather it allows you to disable specific rule(s) within this overall category. This is exactly what I need.

[image]